# How to create multiple instances in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a list of data coming in a request, and after filtering taken out data that needs creation, I'm passing it to the serializer create method, but I'm getting this error:

```
AssertionError: The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `apps.some_app.serializers.SomeSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
```

My view looks like this:

```
class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # Other functions in ModelViewset

    @action(methods=['post'], url_path='publish', url_name='publish', detail=False)
    def publish_data(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        new_data = util_to_filter_data(request.data)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=new_data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.create(serializer.validated_data)
            return Response()
```

I understood the error, that I am passing nested fileds in the create method. But, when I am directly calling my Viewset with single POST request, it is created successfully, even though it too contains nested fields.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my serializer:

```
class SomeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # fields
    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("in create")
        return super().create(validated_data)
    
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        print("in save")
        my_nested_field = self.validated_data.pop('my_nested_field', '')
        # Do some operations on this field, and other nested fields
        obj = None
        with transaction.atomic():
            obj = super().save(kwargs)
            # Save nested fields
        return obj
```

Here `in create` is being seen in terminal, but not `in save`.

Comment: Updated the code structure as suggested by @ashwin-bande, but the serializer `save()` function is not being called for many instances, and getting the same error.

Comment: please refer https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Answer (score 2):

you should not use serializer `create` method directly; instead use `save`. Also no need to check `serializer.is_valid` with `if` when `raise_exception=True`, if it is not valid it will return the exception

Try following.

```
class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # Other functions in ModelViewset

    @action(methods=['post'], url_path='publish', url_name='publish', detail=False)
    def publish_data(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        new_data = util_to_filter_data(request.data)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=new_data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I updated my code similar to your suggestion, but the serializer `save()` is not being called, directly `create()` is called (checked using print statements in both functions). Do you have idea why this would happen?

Comment: the `save` method on serializer calls `create` or `update` depending on the situation. So one thing is sure if `create` is called then `save` must be called.

Comment: does your serializer have nested field? take a look at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: Yes, I have nested fields which are handled in serializer's `save()` method. But it's strange that the print() in save is not being called.

Comment: you should move the code to handle nested field to `create` method. In 99% cases you don't need to explicitly override `save` method of serializer directly, instead `create` and `update` methods should be overrided.

Comment: It's quite an old code, and the handling is probably done in save() because it is required for both create() and update(), and to prevent repetition.

Comment: @KeshavBhatiya Post your save code to analyse root of the problem.

Comment: Theirs no way that happening unless you are calling `serializer.create(serializer.validated_data)` directly from View. Please confirm you are calling `serializer.save()` and **NOT `serializer.create()`** from `MyViewSet`

Comment: Yes, I'm calling `.save()` from my view, and upon further looking at the traceback, I noticed that the flow is directly going to django's save() from my call to `serializer.save()`. I think django is automatically calling **its** `create()` when I call save() from  my view

Comment: if you calling `.save()` from view but it is not executing `print("in save")` which is the first statement of the function. I dont know whats wrong. Please share complete source code; Not redacted by you. I understand the propitiatory concerns but unable to help with unclear information.

Comment: I hope this can give some info, that my save is not called from .save()
`File "/home/ubuntu18/Public/app_location/views.py", line 803, in publish_data
    serializer.save()
File "/home/ubuntu18/Envs/bp_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 720, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)`